# data bricks: spark cluster AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: apache-spark-sql, copy, databricks

i have imported on csv file to data bricks spark cluster now i am getting errors at following steps, though it worked in my local machine where I was not using spark.

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'copy'
`monthly_Imp_data_import_anaplan = monthly_Imp_data.copy()`
`monthly_Imp_data_import_anaplan.fillna(0, inplace=True)`
`anaplan_upload_file = monthly_Imp_data_import_anaplan.astype('string')`
i feel it is because of spark data frame

Answer (score 0):

You are using Pandas Dataframe syntax in Spark.

If you want to continue using Pandas on Databricks then use

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
```

[More details](https://docs.databricks.com/languages/pandas-spark.html)

**Note:** My recommendation will be to learn and use Spark Dataframe (unless you have a unique use case to use Pandas)